# vector of objects containing references

Tags: c++, vector, reference

```
Edge 

{
   Vertex& v1;
   Vertex& v2;
   float cost;
public :
   Edge(Vertex& v_1, Vertex& v_2) :
      v1(v_1), v2(v_2)
   {
   }
   // other getter and setter functions 
};
```

How do I create a vector allEdges ? 
I know I'll have to create a default constructors and assignment operators supported by vector but I can already see this is going to create issues because of non-existence of default constructors.

I have created a default constructor just to get by with the std::vector shouting at me but doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: Having references as member variables is quite restrictive.

Comment: I don't want to use elements there because that would be copying vertices. Though vertices remain const (aren't added/removed) I can't say the same will hold true after 5 years after implementation.

Comment: You could use pointers to `Vertex` though.

Comment: with c++11 emplace_back allow you to have a vector of objects without default constructor. As for the references, they will make your vector not copyable. A workaround would be to use std::reference_wrapper, pointers or boost optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using references as member variable is quite restrictive since they have to be initialized in the initializer list of the constructor.

However, having a vector of objects that in turn have references as member variables is completely allowable, as can be seen in the example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex { 
  std::size_t id;
  Vertex(std::size_t const _id) : id(_id) {}
};

class Edge {
   Vertex& v1;
   Vertex& v2;
   double  cost;
public :
   Edge(Vertex& v_1, Vertex& v_2, double const _c) : v1(v_1), v2(v_2), cost(_c) {}
   Vertex& getv1() const { return v1; }
   Vertex& getv2() const { return v2; }
};

int main() {
    Vertex v1(1), v2(2);
    std::vector<Edge> alledges;
    alledges.push_back(Edge(v1, v2, 1.0));
    for(auto i : alledges) std::cout << i.getv1().id << "->" << i.getv2().id << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f332e8ef6e35c6a)

Comment: That sums up ! Thanks !